# what is RARE organisation in the context of hypertext systems?

Tags: research-process, university

I am digging "dead bodies" meaning that i analyse alternatives to the web system which were popular in early 90s and seems to be found the relevant report.

The problem is author is constantly refers to some unknown organisation called RARE which i found no information about. It existed 20 years ago and was mentioned in numerous examples such as the following with other famous institutuons:

"It is noted that the rapid growth of WWW may in the future lead to problems through the implementation of multiple , uncoordinated and mutually incompatible add-on features. To guard against this trend , it may be appropriate for RARE, in cooedination with CERN and other interested parties such as NCSA, to encourage the formation of a consortium to coordinate WWW technical development. "

So who are these RARE was it institution? I was around 3 when berners lee and all these fellas developed the web so i am out of the context.

Link: www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1614.html

Appologise for typos: posting from phone.

Answer (score 4):

A little detective work reveals the following. From [Chris Adie's Resume](http://chrisadie.wordpress.com/about-me/mini-resume/) it seems that RARE is now called [TERENA](http://www.terena.org/), which is "The Trans-European Research and Education Networking Association". Looking at the history of [TERENA](http://www.terena.org/news/fullstory.php?news_id=1969), reveals that RARE stands for "Réseaux Associés pour la Recherche Européenne", which is a little strange, as it is a Dutch organisation.

Incidentally, one of my old pals used to work for TERENA.

Comment: The RARE acronym is also listed in some of the drafts issued by RARE itself, e.g. [here](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-rare-msg-a-bombs-00).

Comment: @F'x: That seems to be a quite COMMON practice.